# passport js sessions does not work with Cors

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, cors, passport.js

I search a lot on internet but I can not find the answer.

I am using my frontend on one port and my backend in another. I use [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) to enable the requests and this works. But when I implement passport js 
and sessions with mongodb whit does not work, it means when I try to get the user with **req.user** this is undefined. 
Here is my **index.js code**

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
secret: 's3cr3et',
store: new MongoStore({
    url: process.env.MONGO_URI
})
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**my passport js is**

Here i define my auth, serialize and deserialize user. My Auth and serialize is working well **but deserialize not**

```
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done)  {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done)  {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { error: 'Invalid credentials.' }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { error: 'Invalid credentials.' });
    });
  });
}));
```

I tried also cookie session instead mongo db but I guess is not the solution. The problem is the cors, for some reason passport dont read the session.

Also I tried to enable in coors credentials and specify the origin but deserialize still not set the user

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080']
}));
```

I hope you can help me because I can not get it work Thanks !!

Comment: Does it work when you remove the cors()? I'm having the same situation and same issue :(

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta it wouldn't work if you removed cors because you would also disable Cross Origin requests. So the front-end wouldn't be able to make any requests.

Although, I'm having the same exact issue and searched the whole internet. Still can't find a way. I'm searching other ways of Authentication since passportjs doesn't seem to work with cors or I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was having an SPA on the frontend with a RESFful (well, not really as we are maintaining state here) backend on Node.js. Later I found out that I was not sending the browser cookies along with the data when I used to make requests to my RESTful API. This was exactly where the issue was that what was not letting users get Deserialized because we need cookies data on the backend to find out which user has sent a particular request. Try doing the same, I hope that would solve your problem as it did mine. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: I think he means something like this (for future visitors) https://flaviocopes.com/axios-credentials/

Comment: @utkarshPramodGupta so I understand the problem you have described, and what was not happening right. But what, in code, did you do to remedy this situation so it would work?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS), which is a security mechanism set in place to prevent unauthorized browsers from accessing information from servers.

The server and client must both opt-in to allow CORS.

### Server Opt-in

##### index.js

I'm adding this just to have a complete answer.

`origin: "http://localhost:8080"` lets the server know what browser is capable of accessing our information.

`credentials: true` allows requests to include cookies within CORS and is how we let the server opt in.

```js
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080", // origin: ["http://localhost:8080"] works also
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

### Client Opt-in

`credentials: "include"` is our way of letting the browser opt in by sending cookies along with the request.

```js
   await fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
        credentials: "include",
      })
```